# How to grab users on the same page in a session and list them?

Tags: php, ajax, session

[On this page](http://buildworx-mc.com/chat) I created a chat room that only works if you're signed into the forums. It grabs the session username who's on the page and shows your name when you send a chat. The messages are sent and stored and sent out via a .txt file using Ajax and processed with PHP. No database (as of yet).

I'm wondering how can I grab & list the current users on the page that is chatting? I'm not so good with PHP so this is a bit complicated for me.

My guess would to log the username to the database, and then get whoever is logged displayed... Am I close?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php 
 session_start(); 
echo "<pre>";
 Print_r ($_SESSION);
echo "</pre>";

 //echo a single entry
 echo $_SESSION['username'];
?>
```

foreach loop through the ($_SESSION) will show all session data..

```
foreach ($_SESSION as $key=>$val)
    echo $key." ".$val;
```

Comment: I don't understand how this would get every user that is on the page?

Answer (score 0):

You need to save your session data of each user to handle this situation. The storage can be database table or files. Read about session save handlers for PHP to know more about it. See http://phpmaster.com/writing-custom-session-handlers/ and https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.customhandler.php

After storing the session data into a database, you can query all the sessionid's and use the SessionHandler::read(sessionid) function to retrieve the session data.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use active sessions for this.
Instead of sessions you have to count users active in the chat (i.e. users requested chat update within several last update cycles)

You have to store usernames along with timestamps in the file or database, and remove users with expired timestamps from that list.

Answer (score -1):

you'll need to implement a way to track user activity through a db (best option) or file

Comment: Example? Before I guess I would throw the user into the database, and then fetch user from the database into a list and display al the users that are in the table.......

Comment: session data is server-side actually